# Slow GridView performance in Internet Explorer 8 (and compatibility mode)

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, gridview

I should display a fairly large amount of data in a GridView (around 1000 rows per 10-20 columns), and I see that the first rendering is extremely slow in IE8 (also with compatibility mode enabled). The same page loads very fast on Firefox and Chrome, but unfortunately I have to target IE for this project.

What can I do to improve IE's behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Already you know that for large data source the rendering will be slow :)

You can try answers here on this post

[Why do my ASP.NET pages render slowly when placed on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730657/why-do-my-asp-net-pages-render-slowly-when-placed-on-the-server)

On this page Look at this answer link https://stackoverflow.com/a/730732/448407

But prior to this all, Why don't you use paging in the gridview?

This will allow the page to open as the data to render will be less but this will not be a performance boost at the database level.

For that you need custom paging :

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you using javascript to render the page? Or the whole HTML is coming from the server?

If Javascript, then you need to switch to server side rendering. Maybe use DataGrid on the server.

If you have large amount of CSS, especially CSS classes defined as `.parentClass .childCass {....}` then it performs worse in IE.

Another possibility is your page is downloading a lot of script, css, images. IE is usually slower than FF, Chrome is fetching lot of external resources.

So, suggestion would be to:

- Render the HTML directly from server.
- Set `EnableViewstate = false` on the DataGrid.
- Cleanup CSS.
- Reduce number of scripts, css and images.

Let me know if it helps. If not, please prove the html output from your page.